# I got `NoClassDefFoundError` on one machine but the same jar works fine on another machine

Tags: java, java-8, netty

I have packaged my netty project as a jar, and it works fine locally and on one server, but it will throw `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` exception on another one. Furthermore, if I start the jar with `java` from jre instead of `java` comes with jdk (same version), it works again.

If this jar works somewhere, it means the jar has already had the required classes packaged, then what might cause the problem?

```
2022-06-30 10:58:11 WARN  [io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline] : An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.baidu.bjf.remoting.protobuf.utils.JDKCompilerHelper
        at com.baidu.bjf.remoting.protobuf.ProtobufProxy.doCreate(ProtobufProxy.java:397)
        at com.baidu.bjf.remoting.protobuf.ProtobufProxy.create(ProtobufProxy.java:311)
        at com.baidu.bjf.remoting.protobuf.ProtobufProxy.create(ProtobufProxy.java:276)
        at com.baidu.bjf.remoting.protobuf.ProtobufProxy.create(ProtobufProxy.java:249)
        at com.baidu.bjf.remoting.protobuf.ProtobufProxy.create(ProtobufProxy.java:208)
        at com.wjserver.ws.codec.ProtobufDecoder.decode(ProtobufDecoder.java:23)
        at com.wjserver.ws.codec.ProtobufDecoder.decode(ProtobufDecoder.java:40)
        at com.wjserver.ws.handler.WebSocketInHandler.channelRead0(WebSocketInHandler.java:41)
```

...

Comment: Your last sentence isn't true.  Java can look in multiple jars, and even in multiple locations for jars.  It sounds like the required class is in a jar that exists on one machine but not the other, or possibly that the required jar is in a location where java is failing to look.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem However, I also have tried to run this jar on another server with java newly installed with no other libs, and it also works fine. By the way, it worked on the problematic server before and got this problem after I restarted it.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Do you mean there is a chance I have a wrong dependency located on the problematic server? Then where should I find out if there were?

Comment: There's always a chance of a wrong dependency.  If you are using a build tool such as maven or gradle to build your jar, you should be able to get it to sort out your dependencies for you.  If you're not using a build tool, you're in for a world of pain.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I have checked the jar and there are no dependency conflicts, and there is no related jar located on the problematic server. It is so weird.

Comment: What will a class named `JDKCompilerHelper` do when there is no JDK and hence no compiler?